# R: Web scraping .aspx form - no results

Tags: r, forms, web-scraping, rvest

Novice to web-scrapping here...
Similar questions have been posted (and answered) but I can't seem to successfully apply
I'm trying loop over a data set and get some scores (The percentile of atherosclerosis) using the following online calculator: https://www.mesa-nhlbi.org/Calcium/input.aspx
(for example plugging in Score = 30, gender=0(female),Race =3(white),Age=50 will get you 94%)

However I cant seem to get any  results matching the manual execution of the calculator - this is my code:
(+Thanks in advance!!)

```
#if(!require("devtools"))
#install.packages("devtools")
#devtools::install_github("omegahat/RHTMLForms")
#install.packages("XML")

library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
library(RHTMLForms)
(https://stackoverflow.com)library(rvest)

cur_url <- "https://www.mesa-nhlbi.org/Calcium/input.aspx/"
cur_session <- html_session(cur_url)

cur_Form <- html_form(cur_session)

cur_fill <- set_values(cur_Form[[1]],
                   Score = '30',
                   gender='0',
                   Race ='3',
                   Age='50')

cur_set <- submit_form(cur_session, cur_fill,submit = "Calculate")
content(cur_set$response)
```

Using the rvest library I've read the url into a "html_session" variable and extracted the form
via "html_form"

```
cur_url <- "https://www.mesa-nhlbi.org/Calcium/input.aspx/"
cur_session <- html_session(cur_url)
cur_Form <- html_form(cur_session)
```

updated the relevant fields using the set_values function and then used submit_form to execute -

```
cur_fill <- set_values(cur_Form[[1]], Score = '30',gender='0',Race ='3',Age='50')
cur_set <- submit_form(cur_session, cur_fill,submit = "Calculate")
```

however I don't seem to get any relevant results in the cur_set veriable
Any help on the matter will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the web page in a browser (e.g., firefox, chrome) and enable the dev-console, you can see certain `id` fields and such that will help identify what you need.

Up front, `rvest` (1.0.3 in my usage) has deprecated several functions you are using. I believe it'll work for now as-is, but I'm using the recommended functions:

- `session()` in lieu of `html_session()`
- `html_form_set()` in lieu of `set_values()`
- `session_submit()` in lieu of `submit_form()`

```r
library(rvest)
cur_url <- "https://www.mesa-nhlbi.org/Calcium/input.aspx/"
cur_session <- session(cur_url)
cur_Form <- html_form(cur_session)
cur_fill <- html_form_set(cur_Form[[1]], Score = '30',gender='0',Race ='3',Age='50')
cur_set <- session_submit(cur_session, cur_fill,submit = "Calculate")
```

Various things you can get from this:

```r
html_table(cur_set)
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#   X1    X2    X3    X4   
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 25th  50th  75th  90th 
# 2 0     0     0     8
```

From the dev-browser, we find specific areas, notably `scoreLabel` (30) and others:

[image: screenshot of dev-browser showing location of scoreLabel]

Similarly for `percLabel` (90) and `Label10` (`"16 %."`).

From this,

```r
html_nodes(cur_set, "#Label10") %>%
  html_text()
# [1] "16 %."
html_nodes(cur_set, "#scoreLabel") %>%
  html_text()
# [1] "30"
html_nodes(cur_set, "#percLabel") %>%
  html_text()
# [1] "94"
```